# Spring data redis libraries fails to convert Joda DateTime Object

Tags: spring, redis

How can we store and retrieve database objects which have Joda DateTime as a field using spring redis Template?

I have tried passing a custom object mapper in the GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer() method. That object mapper works fine in our application and converts all the database objects(which have DateTime field also) properly. But using the same mapper in GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(), it stores the value as a LinkedHashMap instead of the Type of the Database Object class. How can I store and retrieve the object with the same type as the database object class? Below is the code without passing object mapper which results in the following result.

```
@Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(getJedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer( new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer( new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer( new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        return template;
    }
```

Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field \"era\" (class org.joda.time.DateTime), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: \"chronology\", \"millis\"])\n at [Source:(through reference chain: services->java.util.ArrayList[0]->models[\"dateAdd\"]->org.joda.time.DateTime[\"era\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field \"era\" (class org.joda.time.DateTime), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: \"chronology\", \"millis\"])\n (through reference chain: ->java.util.ArrayList[0]->models[\"dateAdd\"]->org.joda.time.DateTime[\"era\"])"